# Getting 404 error on link but code looks correct

Tags: html, http-status-code-404

I just updated a website I built for a client. There are links to pdf forms. After updating, one of the links gives me a

> "404 Error. Page Not Found."

I can't find anything wrong in the code. The pdf is in the correct file. I cleared my cache and cookies. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

The code for that specific link:

```html
<div class="w3-cell-row" style="width:70%;">
    <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile">
        <img src="Images/Privacy-website.jpg" alt="privacy icon" width="100" height="100"/>
    </div>
    <div class="w3-container w3-cell w3-mobile">
        <a href="forms/AVISO-DE-PRÁCTICAS-DE-PRIVACIDAD.pdf" title="Politica de privacidad" lang="es">POLÍTICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
        <hr>
        Como usa nuestros servicios, queremos estar claro cómo estamos usando su información y en que manera usted puede proteger su privacidad.
    </div>
</div>
```

The webpage itself is: http://drchangdentistry.com/for-new-patients.html
The link is the 3rd one: Polìtica De Privacidad

Thank you!

Comment: We can't explain why a page on your website doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link doesn't work because of the accent in the name of the file. 
You can remove it or correct your link.

Here is the correct link of your file :

http://drchangdentistry.com/forms/AVISO-DE-PRA%cc%81CTICAS-DE-PRIVACIDAD.pdf